# how to per click to reload route and not change route?

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

now i have menu directive and product page in diff module.

here similar menu

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
    <li class="active">
    <a  href="#/product">Products</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

here similar product controller

```
.controller('ProductCtrl', ['$scope','flash','$http','FileUploader','$filter','$cookieStore', function ($scope,flash,$http,FileUploader,$filter,cookie) {
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(angularEvent, current, previous) {
    if ('new_id' in current.params){
            $scope.product_id = current.params.new_id;
            $http.get('/v2/oauth/product/'+current.params.new_id).success(function(data,state,headers,config){
                if(state==200){
                    $scope.product_id = data.answer._id;
                    setProduct_variable(data.answer);
                    flash('Get Product info:'+data.answer['name']);
                }
            })
    }else{
       $http.post('/v2/oauth/product/new').success(function(data,state,headers,config) {
            if (state ==200){$scope.product_id =data}
        });
        flash('Get new Product Id!');
    }
    //console.log(current.params);
});
}])
```

and here is routeProvider config

```
$routeProvider.when('/product',{templateUrl:'/view/product',controller:'ProductCtrl'});
```

***change route is success.but i need reload product in #/product or need write a event to getProductID and clean variable in per click #/product*** ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$route.reload();
```

From the manual:

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

You'll also need to inject $route into your controller.

Comment: i know,,but i have $on $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess').. and where to write

Comment: I need correct position to write code..event or other??

Comment: Inside your $routeChangeSuccess event. Check if the new id matches the current scope id, if not, reload.